# Crontab and PHP

Tags: php, linux, cron, tcpdf

I have this crontab script on my CentOS server:

```
30 09 * * * /usr/bin/php - f /path/to/my/file.php > /same/path/error.log
```

This script is needed in order to create - daily - some pdf files in the subfolder pdf/.
I tried many options (php with or without path, with or without -f, etc.) I tried to change permission for the files in the subfolder (becouse these files are overwrited everyday).
But when I execute the script, here is the error.log:

```
TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: pdf/myfile.pdf
```

But whe i run this script from shell, using

```
php file.php
```

or directly from browser, this is working.
Please, some advice on this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be related to the directory the script is being called from.  Try giving the absolute path of the file you want to create, or otherwise ensure cron has permission to write to the destination.

Comment: maybe You have rights to run the script and crontab user doesn't ?

Comment: I'm working as root. The php scripts ran in cron. But this only, becouse of the files, give the error. Permission? I don't know: i set on chmod 777 all interested files.

Comment: More: I gave chmod +x too to the php file.

Comment: Try this way: 30 09 * * * root /your_path_/file.php > /same/path/error.log. (of cource add exec right, ex. 755) and the file.php should like: #!/usr/bin/php
<?php

  // your code

?>

Comment: Solved giving the absolute path to the pdf files. Thank you everybody :)

Answer (score 0):

Cpanel: wget -O - -q -t 1 http://www.happiweb.net/2014/02/thiet-ke-website-bang-wordpress-gia-re.html

[image]

http://domain.com/a.php: change to your URL